# Appending to multiple lists in a function - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have code that gets information from iTunes based on a search term that returns a list of dictionaries with various media types in it. I would like to group this information by whether or not it is a movie, song, or other media type. I want to do this within a function for later use, and was thinking the best way to do this would be to append each dictionary to a list based on what type it is. I am getting empty lists, even though the input I am putting in the function is a list of 100 dictionaries. Is there a better way to do this? This is my code -

```
    def make_object(list_from_req):
        movie_lst = []
        song_lst = []
        media_other_lst = []
        for d in list_from_req:
            if d['kind'] == 'song':
                song_lst.append
            elif d['kind'] == 'feature-movie':
                movie_lst.append
            else:
                media_other_lst.append
        return movie_lst, song_lst, media_other_lst
```

Comment: thank you, I did need to do that but I am still getting empty lists.

Comment: To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`movie_lst.append` by itself doesn’t *do* anything: it *refers* to the idea of adding to that particular list (which is sometimes very useful!) but it doesn’t *use* it.  You have to pass arguments with `()` to call a function (even if there are 0 arguments).

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed to do!